# UL/LI positioning spacing

Tags: html, css

I have been in this problem for a while now, everytime I resize the navigation bar it keeps on adding 1 line at the bottome if the size ddint match. can anyone help me delete that little space after the contact me tab? thanks in advance.
this is the link of the outcome

[image]

my codes is this
obj.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="obj1.css">
<title>Objective 1</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
<div class="nav">
<ul>
<li class="navbutton"><a href="">About Us</a></li>
<li class="navbutton"><a href="">Our Team</a></li>
<li class="navbutton"><a href="">Education</a></li>
<li class="navbutton"><a href="">Health Care</a></li>
<li class="navbutton"><a href="">Advertising</a></li>
<li class="navbutton"><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

obj1.css

```
body {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

li {
    float: left;
}

.header{
width: 900px;
height: 385px;
background-image: url(header.jpg);
}
.navbutton {
position: relative;
top: 310px;
width: 145px;
height: 75px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 5px;
background-image: url(link.png);
}

.navbutton a {
text-decoration:none;
}

.navbutton:hover{
background-image: url(linkselected.png);
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided enough CSS to recreate the problem:  http://tinker.io/0191d

Comment: this is my the problem, i changed the width in .navbutton to 150px. then it adds another space below like this http://tinker.io/0191d/1

Comment: i also tried adding these 
li:last-child, li.the_last_child {float: right; margin-right: 0px;}

but it doesnt delete the space

Comment: If the width is wrong, then the answer is obvious:  you correct the width.

Comment: **little space after the contact me tab?** ok but **keeps on adding 1 line at the bottom** what do you mean by this?

Comment: Try debugging such issues with firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix this by adding the following rules:

```
//Change the header width to 901px to fit all the tabs
.header{
width: 901px;
height: 385px;
background-color: #ccc;
}

//Change the navbutton to be 146px wide
.navbutton {
position: relative;
top: 310px;
width: 146px;
height: 75px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 5px;
background-color: white;
}

//Remove the margin on the last child
.navbutton:last-child {
    margin-right:0;
}
```

Here is the jsFiddle in case you need it - http://jsfiddle.net/XXczL/

Answer (score 0):

Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3kqG7/) for a fluid layout solution.

This solution uses the `display: table`, `display: table-row`, and `display: table-cell` property values.

### Markup

```
 <div class="header">
     <div class="nav">
        <ul>
           <li class="navbutton">
              <a href="">About Us</a>
           </li>
           <li class="navbutton">
              <a href="">Our Team</a>
           </li>
           <li class="navbutton">
              <a href="">Education</a>
           </li>
           <li class="navbutton">
              <a href="">Health Care</a>
           </li>
           <li class="navbutton">
              <a href="">Advertising</a>
           </li>
           <li class="navbutton">
              <a href="">Contact Us</a>
           </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
  </div>
```

### CSS

```
     body{
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     }

     .nav ul{
        display: table-row;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
     }

     .header{
        width: 900px;
        height: 385px;
        background: #f00 url(header.jpg);
        overflow: hidden;
        border: 1px solid #000
     }

     .nav{
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 310px;
     }

     .navbutton{
        display: table-cell;
        height: 75px;
        background-image: url(link.png);
        padding: 0 4px;
     }

     .navbutton a{
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFCC;
        color: #FF0000;
        display: block;
        height: 100%;
        line-height: 75px;
        text-decoration: none;
        text-align: center;
     }

     .navbutton:hover{
        background-image: url(linkselected.png);
     }

     li:last-child, li.the_last_child{ padding-right: 0; }
     li:first-child, li.the_first_child{ padding-left: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

place all the `<li>` tags in a `<div>`
set css for that `<div id="customDiv">`

`#customDiv {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}`

this will make the left and right margin equal and the extra space is distributed equally on both sides..

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems going on here.  First, you have margins being applied where you don't actually want them.  Even when you correct this, your header's width still causes the appearance of the undesirable "space"

http://tinker.io/0191d/2

Include the following modifications:

```
.header {
    width: 895px; /* or modify the width of the button elements */
}

ul {
    margin: 0 0 0 -5px;
}

.navbutton {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

You could use the `:last-child` selector to remove the margin on the last element, but it doesn't work very well in instances where you actually want your elements to wrap (see: http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/dwbHi).  Also, IE8 doesn't support it.